# Last record query in two linked tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, inner-join

I have a table called 'Purchases':

> PurchaseID, PurchaseDate, Vendor

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ PurchaseID ║ PurchaseDate ║ Vendor ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║          1 ║ 01 jan 2013  ║ XYZ    ║
║          2 ║ 02 jan 2013  ║ ABC    ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

and a table 'PurchaseDetails' linked with it using PurchaseID key:

> DetailID, PurchaseID, ProductCode, Price

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═══════╗
║ DetailID ║ PurchaseID ║ ProductCode ║ Price ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════╣
║        1 ║          1 ║         001 ║ 2.34  ║
║        2 ║          1 ║         002 ║ 3.75  ║
║        3 ║          2 ║         001 ║ 5.93  ║
║        4 ║          2 ║         002 ║ 8.14  ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═══════╝
```

I want to get the Price and the Vendor for the last PurchaseDate given ProductCode.

For example:
If ProductCode is '001' then I want the query to return:
5.93 | ABC

I've tried using a TOP 1 SELECT with a DESC ORDER BY, but I can't get the JOIN part to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the TOP1 approach the below query should work

```
SELECT Vendor, Price
FROM Purchases p
INNER JOIN PurchaseDetails pd on pd.PurchaseID=p.PurchaseID
WHERE PurchaseID = (SELECT TOP 1 PurchaseID FROM Purchases WHERE DetailID = DetailID ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC)
```

You can also use the [Row_Number over](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to achive this

Comment: Thanks, John for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Purchases.Vendor, Purchases.PurchaseDate, PurchaseDetails.Price FROM PurchaseDetails INNER JOIN Purchases 
ON PurchaseDetails.PurchaseID=Purchases.PurchaseID WHERE PurchaseDetails.ProductCode='001' ORDER BY Purchases.PurchaseDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can use a windowing function to get the result.  In this case I used `row_number()`:

```
select vendor, price
from
(
  select p.purchaseId, p.purchaseDate, p.vendor,
    d.productCode, d.price,
    row_number() over(partition by d.productCode order by p.purchaseDate desc) seq
  from purchases p
  inner join purchaseDetails d
    on p.purchaseId = d.purchaseId
) src
where seq = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b664f/5)